# Convert array of array in CSV file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array with two objects, lets say:

```
one=[{ "apple":1, "ball":2},{"apple":2,"ball":5}]
```

and I have another object:

```
two=[{"cat":2}];
```

I'm expecting:

```
two=[{"apple":"1,2", "ball":"2,5", "cat":2}]
```

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you had a try on this?

Comment: Please add the code you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```js
var one=[{ "apple":1, "ball":2},{"apple":2,"ball":5}];
var two=[{"cat":2}];

two = two.concat(one);
var res = {};
for(let ind = 0 ; ind<two.length;ind++)
{
  for(let [key,value] of Object.entries(two[ind]))
  {
    if(res[key] == undefined) 
    {
      res[key] = [];
    }

      res[key].push(value);
  }
}
console.log(res);
```